# Fastest method to replace substring from a Dataframe from key value pairs

Tags: python, pandas, string, dataframe, replace

Assume that I have a DataFrame with dates in European Languages:

```py
In[0]: df_date
Out[0]:
    date
0   ene 1 2021
1   1 ene 2021
2   mar. 1 2021
3   5 mars. 2021
4   10 abr 2021
5   abr. 1 2021
```

And I have another DataFrame with corresponding string mappings

```py
In[0]: df_translate
Out[0]:
    foreign eng
0   ene     jan
1   feb     feb
2   mar     mar
3   abr     apr
4   may     may
5   mars    mar
```

The way I go about replacing these is usually with converting the mapping DataFrame to a dictionary, and then use Series.str.replace()

```
date_replace_dict = df_translate.set_index('foreign',drop=True).to_dict()['eng']
    
for k,v in date_replace_dict.items():

    df_date['date'] = df['date'].str.replace(k,v,regex=False)
```

I have found this process to be a bit slow, I was wondering if there is a better/faster more pythonic way of doing it.

<s>I cannot use the `Series.replace()` method because apparently it requires an **exact** match on the string.</s>

Also please note that, this is a more general question, in the sense that I happen to do this operation a lot on different types of columns containing different types of strings and substrings. So the substrings to be replaced are not necessarily at the start of the string or in any other algorithmically determinable place.

If this is a good way of going about it, then it is fine. But **python** tends to make me feel like I am doing something very wrong whenever I use a loop for achieveing something :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would consider writing it as just one regex substitution like this, to avoid copying the whole Series multiple times. It matters more, the more substitutions you need to apply on each column, of course.

```
import re

pattern = r"\b(" + "|".join(re.escape(k) for k in date_replace_dict) + r")\b"

df['date'].str.replace(pattern, lambda m: date_replace_dict[m.group(0)], regex=True)
```

Here, using word boundary `\b` matchers since it might be required if the words to replace are themselves substrings of each other, but it depends on use case how these should be applied.

Comment: Thanks, this is a cool suggestion, but it does not really work. Apparently str.replace() utilizes re.match() which only matches the beginning of a string. 

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.replace.html

Comment: I could verify that it does indeed work with partial matches, doesn't have to be prefix. Pandas 1.2.4. The docs don't seem to say anything about 're.match' (using a match object, is not the same thing).

Comment: You are correct, I tried it and it works. But it does not work on my full DataFrame, reason being I have a mar followed by a mars in df_translate (and other variations). `df_translate.sort_values('foreign', ascending=False)` takes care of this for this particular problem. Not entirely certain if this would apply in a general substring replacement case

Comment: That's tricky, I've added word boundaries to the example in the answer, but it depends on the use case if that's what you need. Using additional regex features can slow down regex search (shouldn't matter so much for small strings, other overhead dominates?)

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [dateparser](https://dateparser.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#). *Dateparser* will  do all the work for you in converting the *string* to a *datetime* object. Especially in your case, when all thestrings are formatted differently, and there are multiple languages, then using *dateparser* would proabably be the easiest thing to do.

```
>>> import dateparser as dp
>>> dp.parse("10 Jan 2020")
    datetime.datetime(2020, 1, 10, 0, 0)
>>> dp.parse("ene 1 2021")
    datetime.datetime(2021, 1, 1, 0, 0)
>>> dp.parse("abr. 1 2021")
    datetime.datetime(2021, 4, 1, 0, 0)
>>> dp.parse("10 abr 2021")
    datetime.datetime(2021, 4, 10, 0, 0)
>>> dp.parse("2020 dic 25")
    datetime.datetime(2020, 12, 25, 0, 0)
>>> dp.parse("mart 25 14") # mart is dutch for march
    datetime.datetime(2014, 3, 25, 0, 0)
```

You could just apply the `dateparser.parse()` function to your column of string dates and you'd be done!

In other words, I would completely get rid of your *mapping* and try *dateparser* instead.

Here is a list of all of the [languages and locales](https://dateparser.readthedocs.io/en/latest/supported_locales.html) that they support.

Comment: Thanks Nico, The very first thing I tried was dateparser. It literally takes ages for it to parse the entire column, even if I give it the locales to use, that is why I opted for this solution. Besides the question is not particularly about dates, I am looking for a faster method that works for any substring replacement

Comment: I'm glad you tried it. I still think it would be worth taking another look at dateparser again though. You can optimize the parsing by using their lower level class [DateDataParser](https://dateparser.readthedocs.io/en/latest/dateparser.html#dateparser.date.DateDataParser). Also, instead of manually iterating over the dataframe use df.applymap(). Quick question, how many rows does your dataframe have?

Comment: I did use .applymap(). the DataFrame has about 500k rows

Answer (score 1):

```
import pandas as pd

df_date = pd.DataFrame({'date':
                            ['ene 1 2021',
                             '1 ene 2021',
                             'mar. 1 2021',
                             '5 abr. 2021',
                             '10 abr 2021',
                             'abr. 1 2021']})

df_translate = pd.DataFrame(
    {'foreign': ['ene', 'feb', 'mar', 'abr', 'mar', 'jun'], 'eng': ['jan', 'feb', 'mar', 'apr', 'may', 'jun']})
d = df_translate.set_index('foreign', drop=True).to_dict()['eng']
print(df_date['date'].replace(to_replace=d, value=None, regex=True))
```

**Output**

```
0     jan 1 2021
1     1 jan 2021
2    may. 1 2021
3    5 apr. 2021
4    10 apr 2021
5    apr. 1 2021
Name: date, dtype: object
```

Comment: Thanks, so it is doable with a Series.replace(). I also tried your method with a timeit, using Series.replace(0 was slower then the loop by %25 for some reason (when performed on my full DataFrame)